# Display does not work after preseeded network install

Tags: 14.04, server, system-installation, display, preseed

I used the netinstaller and a preseed file to preseed several Ubuntu Server installs. This worked fine, and I can SSH into the machines. However, if I go down to the server room and plug in a VGA cable to any of them, the display does not work.

During the preseeded install, if I connected the same VGA cable, the display worked fine and I could see the installer progress bars.

Any ideas why this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was caused by the "splash" parameter being passed to the kernel at boot by GRUB. Editing `/etc/default/grab` and removing `splash` from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` fixed the problem.

I have not yet figured out how to prevent this from happening at install.